# how to find a value in array of objects with key value pairs

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with key value pairs, I'd like to find the value base on the key I have.

Here is the array:

`const baseColors = [{"WHITE":"rgb(255,255,255)"},{"BLACK":"rgb(0,0,0)"},{"DARK GRAY":"rgb(60,60,60)"},{"MEDIUM GRAY":"rgb(98,98,98)"},{"LIGHT GRAY":"rgb(185,185,185)"},{"POLARIS SQUEEZE":"rgb(242,255,0)"},{"SUNBURST":"rgb(254,227,49)"},{"PRO YELLOW":"rgb(253,214,20)"},{"YELLOW":"rgb(243,194,0)"},{"DEEP YELLOW":"rgb(241,169,0)"},{"ORANGE CRUSH":"rgb(254,134,29)"},{"TANGERINE":"rgb(255,102,0)"},{"ORANGE":"rgb(232,85,0)"},{"RACE ORANGE":"rgb(232,58,0)"},{"TERRA COTTA":"rgb(160,61,1)"},{"RUBY RED":"rgb(137,0,0)"},{"TOMATO RED":"rgb(176,29,5)"},{"LAVA RED":"rgb(182,32,7)"},{"POLARIS RED":"rgb(199,6,7)"},{"INTENSE RED":"rgb(223,37,37)"},{"BURGUNDY":"rgb(93,0,33)"},{"RASPBERRY":"rgb(118,5,66)"},{"HOT PINK":"rgb(170,19,118)"},{"PINK":"rgb(222,103,156)"},{"LIGHT PURPLE":"rgb(136,90,168)"},{"VIOLET":"rgb(72,0,144)"},{"PURPLE":"rgb(48,0,92)"},{"RETRO BLUE":"rgb(14,10,49)"},{"LIGHT NAVY":"rgb(10,23,51)"},{"YAMAHA BLUE":"rgb(0,8,102)"},{"SUMMIT BLUE":"rgb(6,28,89)"},{"VOODOO BLUE":"rgb(11,69,127)"},{"BLUE":"rgb(2,25,200)"},{"OCTANE BLUE":"rgb(1,157,232)"},{"ICE BLUE":"rgb(51,162,184)"},{"AQUA":"rgb(54,188,161)"},{"TEAL":"rgb(0,115,115)"},{"MANTA GREEN":"rgb(173,198,4)"},{"LIME GREEN":"rgb(146,199,1)"},{"KAWASAKI GREEN":"rgb(1,189,1)"},{"APPLE GREEN":"rgb(67,136,0)"},{"CAT GREEN":"rgb(0,117,17)"},{"GREEN":"rgb(1,102,28)"},{"FOREST GREEN":"rgb(0,53,26)"},{"ARMY GREEN":"rgb(48,62,9)"},{"BROWN":"rgb(52,27,23)"},{"TAN":"rgb(136,96,50)"},{"BEIGE":"rgb(218,190,152)"},{"SILVER METALLIC":"rgb(175,178,178)"},{"GOLD METALLIC":"rgb(148,110,44)"},{"COPPER METALLIC":"rgb(130,64,0)"}];`

So I'd like to find the value for example like

```
const baseColor1 = $("[name='color1']").val();
const modelColor1Value = baseLayerColors.find(`${baseColor1}`);
```

But this gives

> TypeError: Original Color is not a function error.

How can I do this?  The structure of the array of objects I think is throwing me off with what the correct syntax should be for an array.find().   Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: The chosen datastructure doesn't fit the task. Use an object (`baseColors = {WHITE: 'rgb(255,255,255)', BLACK: 'rgb(0,0,0)', ... }`) instead, and get the value by referring directly to the key: `modelColor1Value = baseColors[baseColor1]`.

Comment: @Teemu I totally agree, however we don't know what is the source of input object - may be the OP get it as result of some external library function or from some external API...

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski If this was my project, I'd flattened the array down to a simple object after loading the data ... Ofcourse, if the data will be used only a couple of times, that's not an issue, but if it is heavily utilized in the code, I'd consider to change the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const baseColor1 = $("[name='color1']").val();
const modelColor1Object = baseLayerColors.find(colorObj => colorObj[baseColor1]);
const modelColor1Value = modelColor1Object[baseColor1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
baseColors.find(c=> Object.keys(c)[0]==colorName);
```

```js
const baseColors = [{"WHITE":"rgb(255,255,255)"},{"BLACK":"rgb(0,0,0)"},{"DARK GRAY":"rgb(60,60,60)"},{"MEDIUM GRAY":"rgb(98,98,98)"},{"LIGHT GRAY":"rgb(185,185,185)"},{"POLARIS SQUEEZE":"rgb(242,255,0)"},{"SUNBURST":"rgb(254,227,49)"},{"PRO YELLOW":"rgb(253,214,20)"},{"YELLOW":"rgb(243,194,0)"},{"DEEP YELLOW":"rgb(241,169,0)"},{"ORANGE CRUSH":"rgb(254,134,29)"},{"TANGERINE":"rgb(255,102,0)"},{"ORANGE":"rgb(232,85,0)"},{"RACE ORANGE":"rgb(232,58,0)"},{"TERRA COTTA":"rgb(160,61,1)"},{"RUBY RED":"rgb(137,0,0)"},{"TOMATO RED":"rgb(176,29,5)"},{"LAVA RED":"rgb(182,32,7)"},{"POLARIS RED":"rgb(199,6,7)"},{"INTENSE RED":"rgb(223,37,37)"},{"BURGUNDY":"rgb(93,0,33)"},{"RASPBERRY":"rgb(118,5,66)"},{"HOT PINK":"rgb(170,19,118)"},{"PINK":"rgb(222,103,156)"},{"LIGHT PURPLE":"rgb(136,90,168)"},{"VIOLET":"rgb(72,0,144)"},{"PURPLE":"rgb(48,0,92)"},{"RETRO BLUE":"rgb(14,10,49)"},{"LIGHT NAVY":"rgb(10,23,51)"},{"YAMAHA BLUE":"rgb(0,8,102)"},{"SUMMIT BLUE":"rgb(6,28,89)"},{"VOODOO BLUE":"rgb(11,69,127)"},{"BLUE":"rgb(2,25,200)"},{"OCTANE BLUE":"rgb(1,157,232)"},{"ICE BLUE":"rgb(51,162,184)"},{"AQUA":"rgb(54,188,161)"},{"TEAL":"rgb(0,115,115)"},{"MANTA GREEN":"rgb(173,198,4)"},{"LIME GREEN":"rgb(146,199,1)"},{"KAWASAKI GREEN":"rgb(1,189,1)"},{"APPLE GREEN":"rgb(67,136,0)"},{"CAT GREEN":"rgb(0,117,17)"},{"GREEN":"rgb(1,102,28)"},{"FOREST GREEN":"rgb(0,53,26)"},{"ARMY GREEN":"rgb(48,62,9)"},{"BROWN":"rgb(52,27,23)"},{"TAN":"rgb(136,96,50)"},{"BEIGE":"rgb(218,190,152)"},{"SILVER METALLIC":"rgb(175,178,178)"},{"GOLD METALLIC":"rgb(148,110,44)"},{"COPPER METALLIC":"rgb(130,64,0)"}];

colorName = 'BROWN';
color = baseColors.find(c=> Object.keys(c)[0]==colorName);

console.log(color[colorName]);
```

Comment: Could you explain why  you need `[0]` in your code ?

Comment: `Object.keys` return array of object keys. Our color objects in `baseColors` contains only one key - the color name (at index 0) so we read it by `[0]`

Comment: True, but  `['WHITE']` == `'WHITE'`. This will work without [0].

Comment: @Noob yes you right - this is nice shortcut - it works when array contains only one value - because before comparison with string JS convert array to string

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it without Object.keys() can be like below:
This is slight variation from Kamil's solution.

```
baseColors.find(c=> c[colorName]);
```

```js
const baseColors = [{"WHITE":"rgb(255,255,255)"},{"BLACK":"rgb(0,0,0)"},{"DARK GRAY":"rgb(60,60,60)"},{"MEDIUM GRAY":"rgb(98,98,98)"},{"LIGHT GRAY":"rgb(185,185,185)"},{"POLARIS SQUEEZE":"rgb(242,255,0)"},{"SUNBURST":"rgb(254,227,49)"},{"PRO YELLOW":"rgb(253,214,20)"},{"YELLOW":"rgb(243,194,0)"},{"DEEP YELLOW":"rgb(241,169,0)"},{"ORANGE CRUSH":"rgb(254,134,29)"},{"TANGERINE":"rgb(255,102,0)"},{"ORANGE":"rgb(232,85,0)"},{"RACE ORANGE":"rgb(232,58,0)"},{"TERRA COTTA":"rgb(160,61,1)"},{"RUBY RED":"rgb(137,0,0)"},{"TOMATO RED":"rgb(176,29,5)"},{"LAVA RED":"rgb(182,32,7)"},{"POLARIS RED":"rgb(199,6,7)"},{"INTENSE RED":"rgb(223,37,37)"},{"BURGUNDY":"rgb(93,0,33)"},{"RASPBERRY":"rgb(118,5,66)"},{"HOT PINK":"rgb(170,19,118)"},{"PINK":"rgb(222,103,156)"},{"LIGHT PURPLE":"rgb(136,90,168)"},{"VIOLET":"rgb(72,0,144)"},{"PURPLE":"rgb(48,0,92)"},{"RETRO BLUE":"rgb(14,10,49)"},{"LIGHT NAVY":"rgb(10,23,51)"},{"YAMAHA BLUE":"rgb(0,8,102)"},{"SUMMIT BLUE":"rgb(6,28,89)"},{"VOODOO BLUE":"rgb(11,69,127)"},{"BLUE":"rgb(2,25,200)"},{"OCTANE BLUE":"rgb(1,157,232)"},{"ICE BLUE":"rgb(51,162,184)"},{"AQUA":"rgb(54,188,161)"},{"TEAL":"rgb(0,115,115)"},{"MANTA GREEN":"rgb(173,198,4)"},{"LIME GREEN":"rgb(146,199,1)"},{"KAWASAKI GREEN":"rgb(1,189,1)"},{"APPLE GREEN":"rgb(67,136,0)"},{"CAT GREEN":"rgb(0,117,17)"},{"GREEN":"rgb(1,102,28)"},{"FOREST GREEN":"rgb(0,53,26)"},{"ARMY GREEN":"rgb(48,62,9)"},{"BROWN":"rgb(52,27,23)"},{"TAN":"rgb(136,96,50)"},{"BEIGE":"rgb(218,190,152)"},{"SILVER METALLIC":"rgb(175,178,178)"},{"GOLD METALLIC":"rgb(148,110,44)"},{"COPPER METALLIC":"rgb(130,64,0)"}];

colorName = 'APPLE GREEN';
color = baseColors.find(c=> c[colorName]);

console.log(color[colorName])
```

Comment: Nice - I like it - plus one :)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `baseColors` is an array of objects, therefore you need to use [JavaScript's Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to find the correct key.

Please use the following snippet to see how that works.

```js
const baseColors = [{"WHITE":"rgb(255,255,255)"},{"BLACK":"rgb(0,0,0)"},{"DARK GRAY":"rgb(60,60,60)"},{"MEDIUM GRAY":"rgb(98,98,98)"},{"LIGHT GRAY":"rgb(185,185,185)"},{"POLARIS SQUEEZE":"rgb(242,255,0)"},{"SUNBURST":"rgb(254,227,49)"},{"PRO YELLOW":"rgb(253,214,20)"},{"YELLOW":"rgb(243,194,0)"},{"DEEP YELLOW":"rgb(241,169,0)"},{"ORANGE CRUSH":"rgb(254,134,29)"},{"TANGERINE":"rgb(255,102,0)"},{"ORANGE":"rgb(232,85,0)"},{"RACE ORANGE":"rgb(232,58,0)"},{"TERRA COTTA":"rgb(160,61,1)"},{"RUBY RED":"rgb(137,0,0)"},{"TOMATO RED":"rgb(176,29,5)"},{"LAVA RED":"rgb(182,32,7)"},{"POLARIS RED":"rgb(199,6,7)"},{"INTENSE RED":"rgb(223,37,37)"},{"BURGUNDY":"rgb(93,0,33)"},{"RASPBERRY":"rgb(118,5,66)"},{"HOT PINK":"rgb(170,19,118)"},{"PINK":"rgb(222,103,156)"},{"LIGHT PURPLE":"rgb(136,90,168)"},{"VIOLET":"rgb(72,0,144)"},{"PURPLE":"rgb(48,0,92)"},{"RETRO BLUE":"rgb(14,10,49)"},{"LIGHT NAVY":"rgb(10,23,51)"},{"YAMAHA BLUE":"rgb(0,8,102)"},{"SUMMIT BLUE":"rgb(6,28,89)"},{"VOODOO BLUE":"rgb(11,69,127)"},{"BLUE":"rgb(2,25,200)"},{"OCTANE BLUE":"rgb(1,157,232)"},{"ICE BLUE":"rgb(51,162,184)"},{"AQUA":"rgb(54,188,161)"},{"TEAL":"rgb(0,115,115)"},{"MANTA GREEN":"rgb(173,198,4)"},{"LIME GREEN":"rgb(146,199,1)"},{"KAWASAKI GREEN":"rgb(1,189,1)"},{"APPLE GREEN":"rgb(67,136,0)"},{"CAT GREEN":"rgb(0,117,17)"},{"GREEN":"rgb(1,102,28)"},{"FOREST GREEN":"rgb(0,53,26)"},{"ARMY GREEN":"rgb(48,62,9)"},{"BROWN":"rgb(52,27,23)"},{"TAN":"rgb(136,96,50)"},{"BEIGE":"rgb(218,190,152)"},{"SILVER METALLIC":"rgb(175,178,178)"},{"GOLD METALLIC":"rgb(148,110,44)"},{"COPPER METALLIC":"rgb(130,64,0)"}];

function find() {
  const baseColor1 = $("[name='color1']").val();
  
  const modelColor1Value = baseColors.find(color => color[baseColor1])[baseColor1];
  
  $("#result").text(modelColor1Value);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="color1" type="text" value="BROWN" />
<input type="button" onclick="find()" value="Find"/>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: `modelColor1Value` will be the object and not the value of the `baseColor1` in that object.

Comment: Updated to get actual color value from Object found.